# ERROR 000358: Invalid expression when using SelectLayerByAtrribute

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000358

I'm trying to finish a script that select a polygon attribute by location using the arcpy call. Here is my code:

```
project = arcpy.GetParameter(0)

proj_layer = r'memory/' + str('proj')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(project_path, proj_layer)

arcpy.AddMessage("PROJECT_NAME = '{}'".format(project))

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(proj_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "PROJECT_NAME = '{}'".format(project))
```

The variable project_path is the correct path and I know it is because I used a print statement to verify that. I'm thinking that it may be some issue with the expression because the output is:

```
PROJECT_NAME = 'spokane_test'
Failed script UUIDScript...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jhodg1\Desktop\Construction Dev\UUIDScript2.py", line 58, in <module>
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(proj_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "PROJECT_NAME = '{}'".format(project))
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 9727, in 
SelectLayerByAttribute
raise e
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 9724, in 
SelectLayerByAttribute
retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(*gp_fixargs((in_layer_or_view, selection_type, where_clause, invert_where_clause), True)))
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

What happens is that the user is supposed to input the project name as a parameter and then I run the script which will then select the polygon based on its name.  'PROJECT_NAME' is the name of the field that I am querying in the 'project_path' layer and I know it exists and that I'm typing in the right name for the project name because I'm looking at the row so I know. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong and what's making it print out "invalid expression"?

Comment: The back-end data source can affect SQL syntax, try using a file geodatabase feature class to make sure it isn't an issue with the memory workspace.

Comment: Strange name for layer. What 'memory' role here?

Comment: Why are you doing `str('proj')`?  `'proj'` is already a string.

Comment: What is `project_path`?  Where is it defined?

Comment: Probably best to avoid having slash (/) or backslash (\) in the name of a layer, unless you really want to use group layer hierarchies.

Comment: @Son of a Beach project_path is the path of the layer where I am trying to get the polygon from. The path is correct and I know that for sure.

Comment: Add it to the script in your post then.  When posting code, you need to (where possible) include an example of code that is complete (can be copied and tested by others to reproduce the problem) and minimal (is cut down to the minimum amount of code that can reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a python variable called `select_clause` and set it to the embedded format expression as follows:

```
select_clause = "PROJECT_NAME = '{}'".format(project)
```

Then (temporarily print it) use it what was line 58 where the arcpy chokes on the string manipulation inside the parameter usage:

```
print ('Select Clause = ' + select_clause)
arcpy.SelectLay`erByAttribute_management(proj_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", select_clause)
```